# How can my C# Windows app be notified of changes in network status without polling?

Tags: c#, .net, windows

I would like to be notified when the computer's network connection is established (has a valid IP address) and I would like to do this without polling. Is there a Windows API that can provide these notifications?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would start with the  [`System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkChange.NetworkAvailabilityChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.networkchange.networkavailabilitychanged.aspx) event.

Also WMI events might be possible, fired on changes to the set of `Win32_NetworkAdapter` or `Win32_NetworkConnection` instances.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/IP/usenetworklist.aspx

"How to use the Windows NLM API to get notified of new network connectivity"

Answer (score 0):

```
public MainForm()
{
    // Set listener to Check if Network Address Changed
    NetworkChange.NetworkAddressChanged += new
    NetworkAddressChangedEventHandler(AddressChangedCallback);
}

static void AddressChangedCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  MessageBox.Show("Network Changed");
}
```